# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to import exernal js  library which is located here - https://github.com/bcabanes/angular-image-cropper/blob/master/src/imageCropper.js

I downloaded this js file locally within my angular project and in angular.json file I have included this js file into scripts.

I am trying to import the exported module by this library into my directive.ts file. But somehow after referring it inside my directive.ts file when I render it in browser, it gives me error in console -_

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at imageCropper.js:1
```

The line one in imageCropper.js is-- *module.exports = Cropper;*

This is my code inside directive.ts file

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnInit, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

declare var Cropper: any; <= This line throws error in browser console
@Directive({
  selector: 'img[processpic]',
})
export class ImageCropperDirective implements OnInit{  
   //some property and method binders
   ngOnInit(){
     //some directive init code
   }
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: This library does not support angular 6, use this instead https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I know this comlete library from github doesn't support Angular 6, hence I am just trying to use one js file from that whole project imageCropper.js. This file is node module which is also using prototype library inside it. I thought we can use external js library written in node within our angular 6 project, but somehow its not working. I already had look at ngx-image-cropper library, but that has some less features than the one I am intending to use.